# Macro runs perfectly with small files, corrupts large files

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a long macro (at least for me), that automatically formats data from the format we receive it in, to the format we want it in.

It works perfectly on sheets with small(er) amounts of data. However, when I run it on a larger sheet (300,000 cells) the workbook gets corrupted. The only errors it ever throws are clipboard or memory issues (when pasting values or deleting columns, so nothing that ought to corrupt anything). I was wondering if there's any particular reason this happens?

Might be important to add that, for reasons the IT guys refuse to explain, I am forced to use 32-bit excel...

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

' Dialogue boxes

                                                                    'Definitions
                                                                    'NonYearColsString  = Column Letter
                                                                    'NonYearCols         = Column Number
                                                                    'YearCol                = Column with Years in
                                                                    'LastYear               = Last year with data
                                                                    'FirstYear              = First Year with Data
                                                                    'r                          =Last Row with Data
                                                                    'Ready                  = yes/no ready to proceed
                                                                    'Nexxxtsheet           = Name of next sheet as string
                                                                    'Numberofwhatever  = Number of Immigrants/emigrants/Stocks etc
                                                                    'YearColStr             = Column with Years in as a Letter
                                                                    't                          = Variable wait time to allow processing. Dependent on r
                                                                    'NYears                 = Number of years in Dataset
                                                                    'Step                   = Integer value of r/10


Line69:

Range("A1").Select

Dim Ready As String
Ready = InputBox("You need a few things for this to work: You must  - know the range of years, have an empty sheet preceeding the data, and know the column header for the last field that is not a year. NOTE: If the data seems bizarre - recalculate the formulae before crying. If recalculating doesn't work, go back to crying... Input Yes to continue; No to cancel; Check to go to check the data you need.", , "Yes")
If Ready = "Yes" Or Ready = "yes" Or Ready = "y" Or Ready = "Y" Then GoTo Line0
If Ready = "Check" Or Ready = "check" Then GoTo Line10
If Ready = "No" Or Ready = "no" Or Ready = "n" Or Ready = "N" Then GoTo Line100

Line10:
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
Range("A1").Select

Line666:

Dim chill As String
chill = InputBox("Enter go to move to the end of the spreadsheet to see all the values, leave it blank to go back to the main menu")
If chill = "go" Or chill = "Go" Or chill = "GO" Then GoTo Line999
If chill = "" Then GoTo Line333

Line999:
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
chill = InputBox("Enter go to move to the end of the spreadsheet to see all the values, leave it blank to go back to the main menu")
If chill = "go" Or chill = "Go" Or chill = "GO" Then GoTo Line999
If chill = "" Then GoTo Line333

Line333:

Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
GoTo Line69




Line0:
Dim NonYearColsString As String
Dim NonYearCols As Integer
Line1:
    NonYearColsString = InputBox("Input last Column Letter that does not contain a year", , "d")
Range("ZZ67").Value = NonYearColsString
    If NonYearColsString = "" Then GoTo Line100
    If NonYearColsString = "a" Or NonYearColsString = "A" Then NonYearCols = 1
    If NonYearColsString = "b" Or NonYearColsString = "B" Then NonYearCols = 2
    If NonYearColsString = "c" Or NonYearColsString = "C" Then NonYearCols = 3
    If NonYearColsString = "d" Or NonYearColsString = "D" Then NonYearCols = 4
    If NonYearColsString = "e" Or NonYearColsString = "E" Then NonYearCols = 5
    If NonYearColsString = "f" Or NonYearColsString = "F" Then NonYearCols = 6
    If NonYearColsString = "g" Or NonYearColsString = "G" Then NonYearCols = 7
    If NonYearColsString = "h" Or NonYearColsString = "H" Then NonYearCols = 8
    If NonYearColsString = "i" Or NonYearColsString = "I" Then NonYearCols = 9
    If NonYearColsString = "j" Or NonYearColsString = "J" Then NonYearCols = 10

Line33:

Dim YearCol As Integer
YearCol = NonYearCols + 2

Dim YearColStr As String
If YearCol = "1" Then YearColStr = "A"
If YearCol = "2" Then YearColStr = "B"
If YearCol = "3" Then YearColStr = "C"
If YearCol = "4" Then YearColStr = "D"
If YearCol = "5" Then YearColStr = "E"
If YearCol = "6" Then YearColStr = "F"
If YearCol = "7" Then YearColStr = "G"
If YearCol = "8" Then YearColStr = "H"
If YearCol = "9" Then YearColStr = "I"
If YearCol = "10" Then YearColStr = "J"

GoToLine88:

Line88:

Dim FirstYear As String
Line2:
    FirstYear = InputBox("Input the first year of data available", , "2000")
Range("ZZ68").Value = FirstYear
    If FirstYear = "" Then GoTo Line100

Dim LastYear As String
Line3:
    LastYear = InputBox("Input the last year of data available", , "2015")
Range("ZZ69").Value = LastYear
    If LastYear = "" Then GoTo Line100

Dim NYears As Integer
NYears = LastYear - FirstYear + 1

Dim Numberofwhatever As String
Line4:
    Numberofwhatever = InputBox("Input the title of the Field e.g Number of Immigrants", , "Number of Immigrants")
    If Numberofwhatever = "" Then GoTo Line100


    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Counter"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A3").Select
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, NonYearCols).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Counter"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A2:A4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A100000")
    Range("A2:A10000").Select
    Range("A2").Select

    'Once the counter is in place; r can be defined

    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.Copy
    DoEvents
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
    Range("J15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    DoEvents
    Range("J15").Value = Range("J15").Value * NYears
    DoEvents

    Dim r As Long

    r = Range("J15").Value

    Dim t As Integer

    If r < 50000 Then t = "5"
    If 50000 < r < 100000 Then t = "7"
    If 100000 < r < 200000 Then t = "15"
    If 200000 < r < 300000 Then t = "25"
    If r > 300000 Then t = "35"

    Dim Step As Long

    Step = r \ 10

    Range("ZZ64").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NextSheetName()"
    Dim nexxxtsheet As String
    nexxxtsheet = Range("ZZ64").Text
    Range("ZZ65").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = nexxxtsheet

    If NonYearCols = 1 Then GoTo Line7769


    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, YearCol).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year"
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = FirstYear
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=" & LastYear & "," & FirstYear & ",R[-1]C+1)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, YearCol), Cells(r + 1, YearCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(3, YearCol), Cells(r + 1, YearCol)).Calculate
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C[" & YearCol - 1 & "]=" & LastYear & ",R[-1]C+1,R[-1]C)"
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(r + 1, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(r + 1, 1)).Calculate

    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(" & nexxxtsheet & "$A$1,MATCH($A2," & nexxxtsheet & "$A$2:$A$100000,0),MATCH(B$1," & nexxxtsheet & "$B$1:$ZZ$1,0))"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, NonYearCols + 1)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Step, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Step, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
    DoEvents
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step, 2), Cells(Step * 2, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step, 2), Cells(Step * 2, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
        DoEvents
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 2, 2), Cells(Step * 3, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 2, 2), Cells(Step * 3, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
            DoEvents
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 3, 2), Cells(Step * 4, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 3, 2), Cells(Step * 4, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                DoEvents
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 4, 2), Cells(Step * 5, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 4, 2), Cells(Step * 5, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                    DoEvents
                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 5, 2), Cells(Step * 6, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 5, 2), Cells(Step * 6, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                        DoEvents
                        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 6, 2), Cells(Step * 7, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 6, 2), Cells(Step * 7, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                            DoEvents
                            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                                Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 7, 2), Cells(Step * 8, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 7 / 10, 2), Cells(Step * 8, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                                DoEvents
                                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                                    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                                    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 8, 2), Cells(Step * 9, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 8, 2), Cells(Step * 9, NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                                    DoEvents
                                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                                        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, NonYearCols - 1)).Select
                                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Step * 9, 2), Cells(r + 1, NonYearCols + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
                                        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Step * 9, 2), Cells((r + 1), NonYearCols + 1)).Calculate
                                        DoEvents
                                        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                                ActiveCell.Select






    Cells(1, YearCol + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Numberofwhatever
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(" & nexxxtsheet & "$A$1,MATCH(A2," & nexxxtsheet & "$A$2:$A$100000,0),MATCH($" & YearColStr & ":" & YearColStr & "," & nexxxtsheet & "$B$1:$ZZ$1,0))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, YearCol + 1), Cells(r + 1, YearCol + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
     ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, YearCol + 1), Cells(r + 1, YearCol + 1)).Calculate
    DoEvents


    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r + 1000, 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    DoEvents
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(r + 1000, 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(r + 1000, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(r + 1000, 4)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(r + 1000, 5)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(r + 1000, 6)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(r + 1000, 7)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(r + 1000, 8)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(r + 1000, 9)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(r + 1000, 10)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(r + 1000, 11)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range("J15").Value = ""
    Range("A:A").Delete
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    Range("A:A").Delete
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
    Range("ZZ64:ZZ80").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r + 2, 1), Cells(1048576, 1000)).Value = ""

GoTo Line100

Line7769:

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, YearCol).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year"
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = FirstYear
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=" & LastYear & "," & FirstYear & ",R[-1]C+1)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, YearCol), Cells(r + 1, YearCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(3, YearCol), Cells(r + 1, YearCol)).Calculate
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C[" & YearCol - 1 & "]=" & LastYear & ",R[-1]C+1,R[-1]C)"
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(r + 1, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(r + 1, 1)).Calculate


    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(" & nexxxtsheet & "$A$1,MATCH($A2," & nexxxtsheet & "$A$2:$A$100000,0),MATCH(B$1," & nexxxtsheet & "$B$1:$ZZ$1,0))"
    Range("B2").Calculate
    DoEvents
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(r + 1, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault


    Cells(1, YearCol + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Numberofwhatever
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(" & nexxxtsheet & "$A$1,MATCH(A2," & nexxxtsheet & "$A$2:$A$100000,0),MATCH($" & YearColStr & ":" & YearColStr & "," & nexxxtsheet & "$B$1:$ZZ$1,0))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, YearCol + 1), Cells(r + 1, YearCol + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
     ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range(Cells(2, YearCol + 1), Cells(r + 1, YearCol + 1)).Calculate
    DoEvents


    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r + 1000, 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    DoEvents
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(r + 1000, 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(r + 1000, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(r + 1000, 4)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(r + 1000, 5)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(r + 1000, 6)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(r + 1000, 7)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(r + 1000, 8)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(r + 1000, 9)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(r + 1000, 10)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(r + 1000, 11)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    DoEvents
    Range("J15").Value = ""
    Range("A:A").Delete
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    Range("A:A").Delete
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
    Range("ZZ64:ZZ80").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r + 2, 1), Cells(1048576, 1000)).Value = ""

Line100:
End Sub
```

The Main code also calls on a the function NextSheetName:

```
Function NextSheetName(Optional WS As Worksheet = Nothing) As String
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim S As String
    Dim Q As String
    Dim P As String
    If IsObject(Application.Caller) = True Then
        Set WS = Application.Caller.Worksheet
        If WS.Index = WS.Parent.Sheets.Count Then
            With Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets
                Set WS = .Item(1)
            End With
        Else
            Set WS = WS.Next
        End If
        If InStr(1, WS.Name, " ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Q = "'"
        Else
            Q = vbNullString
        End If
    Else
        If WS Is Nothing Then
           Set WS = ActiveSheet
        End If
        If WS.Index = WS.Parent.Worksheets.Count Then
            With WS.Parent.Worksheets
               Set WS = .Item(1)
            End With
        Else
            Set WS = WS.Next
        End If
        Q = vbNullString
    End If
    P = "!"
    NextSheetName = Q & WS.Name & Q & P
End Function
```

Explanation: NextSheetName (found online; not my original work), returns the name of the next sheet so it can be called in the macro without specifying the name. The macro as a whole takes data in this format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/udi14.png

And turns it into this format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CskpH.png

I have included csv versions of two sheets, the first of which corrupts the file, the second of which works fine. Unfortunately, with good reason, my workplace bans file-sharing sites, so I can't upload in a more convenient format...

I need 10 reputation to post more than 2 links so these are formatted to bypass the filter. Just remove the %s to get to the link

The one that corrupts: paste.ee%/p/e1H9x

The one that works: paste.ee%/p/NmAFn

!!!IF YOU WANT TO RUN THIS, I STRONGLY RECOMMEND YOU TURN AUTOMATIC CALCULATION OFF!!!

Thanks for the help everyone, and have a great day!

Lukas

Comment: Firstly see here about questions at SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Usually we need code to locate the problem and help you.

Comment: We can only help you find errors if we see the code. So, you were right with your initial thought to include the code in the post. Please do so and (possibly) also include your Excel version, the line on which the error occurs, specific error messages, (if relevant) sample data to reproduce the problem on our end (with the code).

Comment: And another point that you mentioned in your question. In vba please avoid in general the use of copy paste (it is slow and requires a huge amount of resources for no reason). Propably the clipboard and memory issues you mentioned are the reasons your data are corrupted in bigger xl files.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys, I have now attached non-privileged, csv versions, and the code.

If I want to paste values to get rid of formulae dependencies, how would one do that?

Comment: Hi, this will sound more like a code review then an answer to your question purely because it should help your coding practice. Firstly, your `Macro2` sub is huge. Try splitting it into smaller functions/subs. It will help to maintain and identify issues within your code. Second: try not to use `GOTO`. It makes it harder to read the code or understand the logic in the code. Instead use things like `Select`. Finally (and I will stop at this point) if you just want to get `Worksheet` names, try this the code below

Comment: `Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook`. Then declare a Worksheet object `Dim oWS As Worksheet`. Now you can get sheet names in your workbook by using the following loop `For Each oWS In oWB.Sheets`. You wont need a big function to do that

Comment: Hi Zac,

This is actually my first serious(ish) piece of code, and everything in here is amalgamated from various sources. It took an unrespectable amount of time to make, and I am 3000% certain that nothing in there is done in an efficient or "best practice" manner, so your code review is actually rather helpful for when I need to make macros in the future. The reason for the function is that it returns the name of the next worksheet as a string that I can then define as a var, meaning the code is entirely standardised and can be applied to any workbk. wrdcount noideahowi'ddothatwithurcode.

Comment: In addition to all above comments, also avoid using `Select` unnecessarily, really slows things down.  Eg, instead of `Range("A1").Select : ActiveCell.Value = "Counter"` , just use `Range("A1").Value = "Counter"`

Comment: I will go through my macro and get rid of the unnecessary `Select` s. When is a `Select` statement extraneous, and when is it justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your two samples, this should to do what you're trying to accomplish, if I'm understanding you correctly.  The code isn't optimal, there's no error checking included, but hopefully will get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim wS As Worksheet, wT As Worksheet
  Dim rS As Range, rT As Range, rY As Range
  Dim v
  Dim lRow  As Long 'last used row
  Dim Cnt   As Long 'source row cntr
  Dim FCol As Long
  Dim LCol As Long

' ------change these 2 rows to suit--------
  Const FDATE As Long = 2000 'first year
  Const LDATE As Long = 2015 'last year
'------------------------------------------

  Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("e1H9x") 'source sheet, chg to suit
  Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Modified") 'chg to suit

  On Error GoTo errTrap
' establish year columns
  FCol = wS.Rows(1).Cells.Find(FDATE, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False).Column
  LCol = wS.Rows(1).Cells.Find(LDATE, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False).Column

  wT.Select: wT.Range("a1").Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' add heading if blank sheet
  lRow = LastRow(wT)
  If lRow = 1 And IsEmpty(wT.Cells(1, 1)) Then 'assume blank sheet
    Set rY = wS.Range("a1").Resize(, FCol - 1)
    addHeader wT, rY
  End If

  Set rS = wS.Range("A1", wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'data height
  Set rS = rS.Resize(, FCol - 1) 'columns 1 to Gender
  Set rY = rS.Offset(, FCol - 1).Resize(, LCol + 1 - FCol) 'years columns

  lRow = lRow + 1

  For Cnt = 2 To rS.Rows.Count 'skip over heading row
    v = rS.Rows(Cnt)
    wT.Cells(lRow, 1).Resize(, FCol - 1) = v
    rY.Rows(1).Copy 'years
    wT.Cells(lRow, FCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True
    rY.Rows(Cnt).Copy 'numbers
    wT.Cells(lRow, FCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True
    wT.Cells(lRow, 1).Resize(rY.Columns.Count, FCol - 1).FillDown
    lRow = lRow + rY.Columns.Count 'next row
    If (Cnt Mod 1000) = 0 Then DoEvents 'every 1000 iterations
    Application.StatusBar = Cnt
  Next Cnt

  wT.Cells(1, 1).Select
errTrap:
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Function LastRow(w As Worksheet) As Long
' checks cells in column 'A'
  Dim c As Range
  Set c = w.Cells(w.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
  LastRow = c.Row
End Function

Sub addHeader(w As Worksheet, r As Range)
  Dim rT As Range
  Set rT = w.Range("a1").Resize(, r.Columns.Count)
  rT.Value = r.Value
  rT(1, 1).Offset(, rT.Columns.Count).Value = "Year"
  rT(1, 1).Offset(, rT.Columns.Count + 1).Value = "Number of Immigrants"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DaveU !

Comment: I tried it, and after some quick playing around, I could get it to work, and I managed to standardise it so it would play with all the configurations of sheets that I have. Thank you very much; I am very grateful that you took the time to do this.

Comment: One quick question- I turned off "recalculate workbook before saving", and that meant that meant that the workbook didn't get corrupted, even using my, let's say, less than optimal macro. However, as all the formulae are pasted as values, to me it seems as though that shouldn't make a difference... Why does it?

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found it useful.  As to the "recalculate workbook before saving" question, hard to say without seeing your actual workbook.  It seems to me there might still be some formulas "hiding" somewhere in your workbook - just a guess!

Comment: That would be the reasonable guess Dave, but it's bizzarre, because there really oughtn't be because the macro pastes everything as values as the last thing it does! I am truly at a loss!

Comment: Without seeing your original data I'm afraid I'm also out of ideas.  I did try your links, `ee%/p/e1H9x` and `ee%/p/NmAFn`, but I couldn't get them to work, even after removing the `%`.  Obviously I'm missing something, not sure what.

Comment: the website is paste.ee

Comment: so it's paste.ee/xxxxxxxx

Comment: Ok, I managed to get into those links. The problem with the large file is because (1) The data layout has an extra column, and (2) there's some extraneous data to the right that's messing up the establish range routine. So to get around that I've made a few modifications to make things more flexible. So going with the assumptions that your data starts at A1 and your years columns are to the right, you just need to change two constants FDATE and LDATE. This will establish the ranges, allowing for x number of columns to the left of the years and ignore any data to the right.

Comment: I've now run this successfully on both files, the smaller one takes about 4 secs on my machine, the larger file takes just under 90 secs. Hope this helps.